# String To Float conversion in Arduino

Tags: string, arduino

How to Convert a string in float up to 3 decimal places in Arduino?
My string is 
23.455 but when I convert it into float by toFloat() method it gives 23.45 and removes last digit.

Comment: Please, post your code. We can't find an error in a code that we aren't seeing. We aren't magicians... not yet.

Answer (score 2):

```C++
void setup ()
{
  Serial.begin (115200);
  float f = atof ("23.455");  // convert to float
  Serial.println (f, 3);      // print with 3 decimal places
}  // end of setup

void loop ()
{
}  // end of loop
```

Output:

```
23.455
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that.. float holds the whole value up to 3 decimal places but it just print up to 2 decimal places so the float value can be use for calculation

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful. [ArduinoFloatToString](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/FloatToString)